# 3D nonogram – The one-thousander

Tags: visual, grid-deduction, three-dimensional, nonogram

This is a **three-dimensional nonogram**. The first ten squares depict the layers of a $10\times10\times10$ cube. The final square gives the enumerations for the Z-axis, top to bottom. Some rules:

- If a row or column has no numbers, that means that the composition of that row/column is **unknown**. Note that this is different than the usual practice in nonograms where a missing number means that the row/column has no shaded cells at all. In our case, such rows can be explicitly marked with a zero.
- The Z-axis enumerations are all single digits, so e.g. 11 means two stretches of one, not one stretch of eleven.
- The thin black lines in the middle are just visual aids. They're not meaningful to the puzzle itself.

> [image]

What day is it?

Comment: A picture equals a thousand... *grids*? +1ed

Comment: Given what the correct answer is, this question deserves way more upvotes! ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There might still be some mistakes, but I think this is the solution:

> [image: ![enter image description here]

The image is not what I previously thought, which was

> A firework show for the 4th of July
>  [image]

It is actually

> A tree with presents, for Christmas day
>  [image]

Comment: Nice job! A couple of "pixels" are off (e.g. row 5, column 7 currently has 10 shaded cells instead of 6&2), but overall that looks like the correct image. What I was trying to draw was a rot13(Puevfgznf gerr jvgu cerfragf haqrearngu), but I won't blame anyone for not seeing that from the final picture :D The animated image is certainly convincing, even though it wasn't what was intended.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. It seems obvious now but I think I would have had a hard time guessing it. I have tried to fix up the errors, it is hard work to check 100 vertical columns :)